# Can I check which devices are currently streaming on HBO GO?

Tags: hbo-go

Sometimes when I try to watch videos on HBO GO, I'm given the following error message.

> Can't play video. You're streaming HBO GO on too many devices
>   simultaneously. To continue, stop streaming HBO GO on another device.

As far as I can tell, I'm not watching HBO GO on any other device. I was watching on my desktop earlier, but that was nearly half an hour ago.

**Is there a way for me to check what devices are currently streaming HBO GO?**

[image: HBO GO Streaming error]

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to check what devices are currently streaming**, as far as I know.

> Your HBO subscription applies to your household. You can sign in to
>   HBO GO on different devices, but the number of simultaneous streams is
>   limited for security reasons. The username and password that you sign
>   in with should not be shared with anyone outside of your household. If
>   you share your sign-in information, you might not be able to watch
>   videos because too many people are using your profile at the same
>   time.
>
> If you're getting a "too many simultaneous streams" error message, try
>   the following:
>
> - **Step 1: Sign out, quit browser, then sign back in**
>
> *Have everyone in your household sign out of HBO GO (to do this, go to Settings and choose Sign Out), then quit their browser (don't just
>   close the tab, but quit the app). Then open your browser again, sign
>   back into HBO GO, and try playing a video again. If this doesn’t help,
>   try the next step.*
>
> - **Step 2: Sign out and restart your device**
>
> *Have everyone in your household sign out of HBO GO and restart their device. Now have each person sign back in and try playing a video
>   again. If this doesn’t help, try the next step.*
>
> - **Step 3: Wait 30 minutes**
>
> *Have everyone in your household sign out of HBO GO and wait 30 minutes. Then have each person sign back in and try playing a video
>   again*

Taken from official help centre [article](https://help.hbogo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204334008--I-ve-exceeded-the-number-of-simultaneous-streams-What-should-I-do-).

Comment: My account is provided by my university, meaning it only allows for 1 device to stream at once. This means I can't really fix the issue without knowing what devices are streaming.

Comment: Make sure to Sign Out of the account not simple quit the browser. HBO is a cumbersome and annoying website and there simply isn't a better fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, signing out did not solve the issue.

Comment: The only other suggestions I can think of are clearing your browser cache. There is no current way of accessing a list of who is currently streaming on your account.